# Parameter of the applet

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, applet, ip-address

I'm displaying some values like IP address in the applet. How to get the parameter of the Ip address in order to pass to the presentation layer.

Here is my HTML code for calling the applet:

```html
<applet code="applet.class" archive="applet.jar" width=200 height=200>
```

private String getIPAddress(){

```
    InetAddress ip = null;
    String inet = null;

    try {
        ip=InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        inet=ip.getHostAddress();
        System.out.println("IP In IP Method :" + inet);

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return inet.toString();
}
```

i'm calling this in draw method:

g.drawString("IP Address =" + getIPAddress(), x, y + 100);

and using the above applet code i'm able to display it in the browser.

so i need to get the ip address which is displayed in browser to the presentation layer.

Comment: If you can put an `ipAdress` `param` in an applet, I can spoof it.  Does that spoil the idea?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean exactly.
Perhaps

```
String ipAddress = java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()
```

may satisfy your need.

Comment: i'm displaying the ip address in browser using an applet with code which u gave above but i need to get the ip value to the presentation layer(and then send it to service layer) and so that i need to save the ip address in data base

Comment: An applet can make a post to another HTML or script of the web app.

Comment: That sound like you need to work with server side (JSP etc), not client side (Applet). For example, if server side use JSP, something like `${request.getRemoteAddr}` in your *.jsp is required.

Comment: i'm using jsf and spring webflow

Comment: Please don't put chunks of code in comments, instead add it as an [edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16413675/edit).

Comment: I'm not familiar with neither of them, but basic idea is that you get `HttpServletRequest` instance somehow and call getRemoteAddr() on that instance.

Comment: <f:verbatim><applet name="fgbapplet" id="fgbappletid" code="ae.endpoint.applet.class" archive="/WEB-INF/template/fgbapplet.jar" width="200" height="200">
</applet></f:verbatim>


it is not working giving classnotfoundexception in jsf